# Spring boot liberty jndi configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jndi, websphere-liberty

Im trying t use jndi config with IBM Liberty, I have configuration like below;

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/sbdatasource
```

liberty server.xml:

```
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
        <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <webContainer deferServletLoad="false" />

    <library id="oracle-lib">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar" />
    </library>

    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/sbdatasource">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="oracle-lib" />
        <properties.oracle user="user" password="pass"
            url="url"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
    </dataSource>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to 
        the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"
        id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="pss" />

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

    <webApplication id="appid" location="app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
        name="app" />
</server>
```

I have theese configuration but Im getting error like that:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/sbdatasource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/sbdatasource.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2523) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1054) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6562) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1004) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:825) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.ModuleHandlerBase.deployModule(ModuleHandlerBase.java:100) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedModuleInfoImpl.installModule(DeployedModuleInfoImpl.java:50) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:420) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:406) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module_1.0.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:66) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war_1.0.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:141) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1191) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:804) [com.ibm.ws.app.manager_1.1.15.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/sbdatasource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/sbdatasource.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/sbdatasource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/sbdatasource.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/sbdatasource'; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/sbdatasource.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fceaa70.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fceaa70$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ad4ee895.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fceaa70.dataSource(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/sbdatasource.
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WSContext.resolveObject(WSContext.java:134) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WSContext.lookup(WSContext.java:300) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.WSContextBase.lookup(WSContextBase.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161) ~[na:na]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

What is the worng with my configuration. Thanks already for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a later oracle driver, ojdbc6 is designed for jdk6. Not sure whether this solves your problem but you should avoid out of date components anyway. So use ojdbc8 (or7) depending on your jdk. The number should match.

Regards Peter

Answer (score 0):

I can spot one error in your dataSource configuration but it wouldn't cause the problem you are seeing.  The attribute,

```
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

does not belong on `properties.oracle`, it belongs on `dataSource`.  But this would only cause you to end up with the default of  javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource instead of javax.sql.DataSource, which shouldn't cause any issues.

If you haven't already, check the server logs for any errors/warnings related the dataSource, jdbcDriver, or library.

Lacking that, the most likely candidate for errors would be in specifying the library for the Oracle JDBC driver.  To debug, temporarily try changing the fileset dir to the absolute path to the Oracle driver, or set it relative to the server location, for example, ${server.config.dir}.  It might be that dir="lib" isn't pointing at where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, as it might also be because of the API-visibility?

I'd suggest adding a shared lib.

```
<webApplication id="appid" location="app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
    name="app">     
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="oracle-lib" apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party" />
</webApplication>
```

and adjust the lib-inserting as well:

```
<library id="oracle-lib" apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar" />
</library>
```

then load a jdbc-driver via

```
    <jdbcDriver id="OracleDriver" libraryRef="OracleLib" javax.sql.DataSource="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
```

then for your Data-Source:

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/sbdatasource" jdbcDriverRef="OracleDriver">
        <properties.oracle user="user" password="pass" url="url"/>
    </dataSource>
```

assuming your URL is also correct there.